# Position Sticky : Sticky Nav Doesn't Work On Safari Browser

Tags: css, sass

i don't know what i'm doing wrong here but my nav doesn't stick to top of cart on safari also sometimes it doesn't work on other browsers which i really didn't understand how. I've tried position fixed for nav but none of my tries didn't work. Hope someone can help me to understand the issue here. Thanks in advance.

```
   <div class="cart">
      <nav>
         ...
      </nav>
   </div>

 .cart {
      position: fixed;
      overflow-y: scroll;
      z-index: 10;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      transform: translateX(100%);
      background-color: white;
      color: #ffff;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }
      nav {
        font-family: abeja;
        position: sticky;
        position: -webkit-sticky;
        z-index: 11;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 20px;
        display: flex;
        background-color: #fff;
        color: gray;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 13px 0 rgb(230, 230, 230);
      }
```

Comment: "_sometimes it doesn't work on other browsers_" when, on which other browsers?

Comment: Sometimes it doesn't work on chrome tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply add `position: -webkit-sticky;`

Comment: I've tried that , it doesn't work at all. This works on iphone 7, and X but it doesn't work for iphone 6.

Comment: I think it is not compatible on Iphone 6 : https://caniuse.com/?search=sticky

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
position: sticky;
position: -webkit-sticky;
```